# Showing Different values in multi pick list

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type, multi-select

I created VF page with a Multi - picklist field using `<apex:inputField value="{!obj.Hobbies__c}" />`

But the values in VF page Multi - picklist showing the different values compare with values in the object field. I got a record types in this object as well.

```
<apex:page controller="controllerClass">
  <apex:form > 
      <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo_Medium}" style="height:150px;width:150px;" rendered="{!Logo}"/>
      <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo_Transparent}" style="height:67px;width:337px;" rendered="{!InLogo}"/>
       <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Lead Edit">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
          <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!dosave}"/>
          <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!doCancel}" immediate="true"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2"> 
              <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                  <apex:outputlabel value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.Fields.FirstName.label}"> 
                  </apex:outputlabel>
                     <apex:outputpanel >
                         <apex:inputfield value="{!lead.Salutation}" ></apex:inputfield>
                         <apex:inputfield value="{!lead.FirstName}" ></apex:inputfield>
                     </apex:outputpanel>
              </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.LastName}"/>
              <apex:selectList label="Campaign" size="1" value="{!CampaignName}" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!ActiveCampaign}" ></apex:selectOptions>
              </apex:selectList>
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Street}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.LeadSource}" />
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.City}"/> 
              <apex:inputfield value="{!lead.PostalCode}"></apex:inputfield> 
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Phone}"/> &nbsp;
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.MobilePhone}"/> &nbsp;
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Email}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!lead.hobbies__c}"/> // multiPicklist 
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
     <apex/page:block>
  </apex:form>
```

Comment: Please put some code here.

Comment: If I recall correctly picklists will respect recordtype selections if you'll add it (as `<apex:outputField>`) to the page, can you try it? If you'll add it as inputField you might have to rerender the page for the picklist to "refresh" itself though

Comment: placed some code <apex:inputField value="{!lead.hobbies__c}"/> // multiPicklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea i've got is that you are reading the picklist values, not labels `toLabel(Hobbies__c)`.

Comment: yeah, the values i given in object are different to the values  displaying on vf page

Comment: Lets say you've entered values like '1,2,3,4,5' to the objects picklist. At your VF page you will get the same values unless you create translations for that values in the translation workbench.

Comment: Okey i entered values like '1,2,3,4,5' to the objects multi-picklist. In Vf page getting the different values 'level a,level b,level c,level d,level e'. and their are some record types to this object

Comment: 1. Check the translations for that picklist
2. Go to the object and check your record type - you can define which values for which record type must be shown

Comment: values are defined to record types but i am unable to display those values in vf page

Comment: So you cannot see the values at all or you see the different values? The point here is, which RecordType has your current "lead" object. Try to find it out and then check the picklist setting (Hobbbies__c) for that record type. Check translations too.

Comment: Hi Mast, I am new to salesforce a new starter. i can see the different values. I know the current record type but how to check the picklist setting for the record type and translations.

Comment: It's easy. To check the recordtype go to the object page (where you can can see all the fields and other info) and scroll down to record types list. Click on the record type you want to check and at the next page find you picklist "Hobbies". Click on "edit". You will see which picklist values are available for this recird type. Check Translations like this: Go to "Setup > Translation Workbench > Translate". Select "Language" and as "Setup Component" select "Picklist Value" and then select your Object. You will see the list with all picklists. Click on [+] Hobbies - you will see translations.

Comment: Yes i can see the list of Hobbies should i need to tick the values the one which i want

Comment: here i can see the my vf page values and object values as well

Comment: i checked the record type when i clicked on edit i can see the pick list values available for this record type. here i can see Available Values & Selected Values. in my vf page the values are displaying from Available Values but not from Selected Values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6704/discussion-between-rakesh-and-mast0r)